# Why does casting this string in this way work but not the other way?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am reading data from Firestore. I was getting an error that said `type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`, so I changed the `createDate` line below to use `.toString()` instead of doing `as String`. This solved the problem, but why did this work?

```
Notification.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic>? json): //Transform JSON into Notification
        createDate = (json?['createDate']).toString(), //This works
        modifiedDate = json?['modifiedDate'] as String; //This gives the error: 'type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast'
```

The format of both of these fields is `October 5, 2022 at 10:49 PM UTC-5`.

Comment: Every `Dart` object has a [`.toString()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Object/toString.html) method inherited from the base `Object` class.  This is just a normal method; it has nothing to do with casting.

Comment: because you're trying to say that "Timestamp" is a String and is not... so, it can't cast it that way but "toString" it doesn't matter what the object is, it will convert to a String. you 3rd line should be "as Timestamp"

Comment: Most of Dart will want a DateTime not a Timestamp.  Luckily, there's Timestamp.toDate() and Timestamp.fromDate(dt).  You would use them here, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json?['createDate']` is a [Timestamp](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Timestamp-class.html) type object that just contains numbers describing a point in time.  As you can see from the API documentation, it has a method called [toString](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Timestamp/toString.html) that knows how to convert that to formatted date string.  Since a Timestamp it is not a subclass of String, Dart does not allow it to be cast to one.  Perhaps you want to cast it to Timestamp instead, since that's what it is?

Answer (score 2):

Like it is said in error message, you are getting this error, because **the value's type, which is coming from json is Timestamp, not String**. It is better to make *createDate* and *modifiedDate* fields in **Timestamp** type instead of **String**, because it provides it's own methods, that make your work easier. Converting to String (and probably, you are parsing this String in somewhere) is **redundant**.

Answer (score 2):

In Flutter every object class have **toString()** method, which is return a value with String type

```
(json?['createDate']).toString();
```

So if you write that code above, it will return a value with String type and then assign that value to `createDate` variable. It means you not assign `json?['createDate']`.

```
modifiedDate = json?['modifiedDate'] as String;
```

That line above will error because you assign that json to modifiedDate which is have different type. Cast (`as`) only work if the object/variable have same hierarchy, like

```
Child child = Child();
Parent parent = child as Parent();
```